# Custom Print Dialog Question

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm still working on a custom Print Dialog and all is progressing well.

My current issue has to do with the Collate options.  The specs I'm following require me to remove it.  I can use Spy++ to specify the ControlID.  Is there a way to hide or not display it on my custom dialog?

Comment: You need to link to the prev question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the control id you can call [GetDlgItem](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetDlgItem.html) to get the window handle and pass it to [ShowWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ShowWindow.html) to hide the control (O' the irony).